# SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server CE (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm looking at the possibility of using the tool [SQLMetal](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Using-SqlMetal-to-generate-Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database-classes). I was wondering is there a way I can create a basic DB using SQL Server 2008 and then convert that to a `.sdf` so I could then use the SQLMetal tool to create the appropriate WP7 classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use my SQL Server Toolbox add-in (or if you do not have Visual Studio Pro or higher, you can use my command line utilities). The toolbox allows you to script a SQL Server 2008 database and run this script against a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database. The toolbox can also create the DataContext and related classes via a simple GUI. See my blog for more info: http://erikej.blogspot.com

Comment: From what I've seen so far, it looks like I can at least convert my SQL DB to .sdf which I should be able to use SQLMetal at that point in time.  I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks for this post!

Comment: But using my Toolbox or command line utility you can create a "better" DataContext - see this blog post: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/06/sql-server-compact-toolbox-22visual.html

Comment: That looks like a 1 stop shop.  I'll give that a go and let you know.